# Can you answer amen to a non-Jewish blessing or prayer of a gentile?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, gentiles, amen

Is a person allowed to answer amen to a prayer or blessing of a gentile? I would assume you can unless the prayer specifically of an idolatrous nature. For example in Christianity saying grace before eating or the [Lord's Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Prayer) neither of which refer in any explicit way to Jesus. I would furthermore assume it is permitted to answer amen to the phrase *allahu akbar* (God is the greatest) as Rabbi Froman himself [uttered this phrase](https://youtu.be/dcPXkobaBU8?t=332) in an effort to make peace.

**Note: I am asking about a non-Jewish prayer only**

Comment: just as an FYI Rav Aviner paskened one may not say amen to the blessing of a non-Jew, it is a blessing in vain http://www.ravaviner.com/2021/06/short-and-sweet-text-message-q-405.html

Answer (score 2):

The impression from Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 215:2 would seem to be that one can answer amen only provided that the normative formula of the blessing remains unchanged:

> אֲבָל אִם הָיָה הַמְבָרֵךְ אֶפִּיקוֹרוֹס אוֹ כּוּתִי אוֹ תִּינוֹק, אוֹ הָיָה גָּדוֹל וְשִׁנָּה מִמַּטְבֵּעַ הַבְּרָכוֹת, אֵין עוֹנִין אַחֲרָיו אָמֵן. הַגָּה: וְעוֹנִין אָמֵן אַחַר עַכּוּ''ם, אִם שָׁמַע כָּל הַבְּרָכָה מִפִּיו (הר''י פֶּרֶק אֵלּוּ דְּבָרִים).
>
> But if the one making the blessing is a heretic or a Samaritan or a child, or he is of age but changed the formula of the blessings, one does not answer amen after him. Ramo: And we answer amen after a gentile provided the entire blessing was heard.(RI ch. Elu Devarim).

The Ramo's ruling regarding the blessing of a gentile is interpreted by the [Be'er Hetev](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.215.2?lang=bi&p2=Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.215.3&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) citing the Magen Avraham as limited to scenarios where the gentile is not an idolator.

The Shulchan Aruch's ruling is based on a Mishna [Berakhoth 51b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.215.2?lang=bi&p2=Berakhot.51b.20&lang2=bi):

> ועונין אמן אחר ישראל המברך ואין עונין אמן אחר כותי המברך עד שישמע כל הברכה כולה:
>
> And one answers amen after a Jew who recites a blessing (even if he did not hear the entire blessing), and one does not answer amen after a Samaritan [Kuti] who recites a blessing until he hears the whole blessing in its entirety, (as perhaps the Kuti introduced an element inconsistent with the Jewish faith in that section of the blessing that he did not hear).

It does not make a difference  in which language Birkat hamazon is said in any language not only Hebrew.

Sotah 32a

> אלו נאמרין בכל לשון פרשת סוטה ווידוי מעשר קרית שמע ותפלה וברכת המזון וושבועת העדות זושבועת הפיקדון.
>
> These can be said in all languages etc.. Grace after meals

Also there is no set text needed Bdieved (i.e If one said grace without mentioning Malchus-His Kingship then one has fulfilled his obligation to bless G-d, though not ideally)

Brachot 40b

> כרך ריפתא ואמר בריך מריה דהאי פיתא אמר רב יצא והאמר רב כל ברכה שאין בה הזכרת השם אינה ברכה דאמר בריך רחמנא מריה דהאי פיתא והא בעינן שלש ברכות מאי דיצא דקאמר רב נמי יצא ידי ברכה ראשונה מאי קמשמע לן אע"ג דאמרה בלשון חול
>   ... Bircat hamozon (Grace) if said (in short form) "Blessed be the L-rd of this bread" he has fulfilled the first Brocho (Blessing) even in a profane (shortened) language.

Comment: My understanding is that Cuttim are in an "interim" category - part Jews part not. I don't think one can infer laws of Aku"m from Kutim.

Comment: please see the edit to the question. I am not asking about a non-Jew making a Jewish blessing, but rather a non-Jewish blessing/prayer.

Comment: +1 @rikitikitembo loewian is right Sotah 32aאלו נאמרין בכל לשון אפרשת סוטה בווידוי מעשר גקרית שמע דותפלה הוברכת המזון וושבועת העדות זושבועת הפיקדון. Grace can be done in English and is equivalent to saying  it in hebrew

Comment: @user15464 Birkat Hamazon is not equivalent to the non-Jewish version of 'grace'

Comment: @rikitikitembo if even for them saying a *Jewish* blessing we have to hear the whole thing to make sure they didn't change anything, then it seems to me that if they make a non-Jewish blessing -- by definition, a change from any *b'racha* that might have applied -- then we wouldn't say amen because of the change.  Maybe Loewian knows of sources that make that argument (or would like to make it himself)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio that line of reasoning would be refuted by the talmudic logic construct called dayo l'vo min ha'din. If you would argue that a Jew would have to listen to the whole non-Jewish blessing to make sure nothing sacrilegious is said before she says amen, I could hear that. But logically you cannot extrapolate beyond the parameters of the original source.

Comment: @rikitikitembo i've answered your last query in the edit

Comment: @user15464 you are fundamentally misunderstanding the question. I am not asking about a non-Jewish person saying a Jewish blessing such as birkat hamazon. I am asking about a 100% non-Jewish prayer, not formulated by Chazal or anyone else in the Jewish religion. You are mistaking the word 'grace' for a pseudo-translation of Birkat HaMazon. I am referring ONLY to the non-Jewish versions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_(prayer)

Comment: @rikitikitembo The Mishna in Sotah does mention that prayer can be said in any language and the Gemora in Brochos seems to acknowledge a profane language as long as directed towards Hashem and not Yimach Shemo Vezichro

Comment: @user15464 that gemara is talking about a Jewish person uttering a blessing and fulfilling (or not) his/her obligation and is therefore irrelevant to the question

Comment: @rikitikitembo your statement is not true see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/does-a-child-get-reward-for-mitzvos-performed where it is evident that a gentile can perform mitzvot like a Jew they are not excluded. By the way Im doing this because i want to spread the truth i dont gain if you aknowledge someone elses answer

Comment: @user15464 you continue to misunderstand the intent of the question. I am not asking about a non-Jew who is trying to perform a mitzvah, I am asking about a non-Jew who is praying to God not in accordance with Judaism but in accordance either with the non-Jew's personal religion or simply a prayer s/he made up

Comment: @rikitikitembo thats what i meant that make sure hes speaking to hashem and not yemach shemo vezichro as a prayer of thanks or beseaching is a prayer there is no prerequisite of associating the prayer to the Jewish religion we see that with Avraham, The king of Moab in the time of Yehoshafat, and Iyov (according to those that say that he was not Jewish