# Non-Jews reciting Jewish Prayers

Tags: halacha, tefilla

I am trying to figure out why it bothers me so much - I mean extremely - for gentiles to say Jewish prayers. I study with a group only two of whom are Jews. Periodically, someone will bring in a Jewish prayer, like the Shema, V'ahavta or Modeh Ani for instance, as in this morning. My skin crawls. I really want to stop them... vehemently. Is this because I am some kind of crazy, horrible elitist or is there some Jewish basis for this?

Comment: @ J. Cohen. Welcome! Isn't there some discussion on whether Shema is prayer or torah.  The Prayers are probably ok, except that learning torah, with the exception of Noahid's in regard to their won commandments, is of course not on for gentiles. I understand how you feel though.

Comment: Modeh Ani doesn't mention anything about Jews.  Non-Jews may not be required to say it, but I would find it hard to argue that it's not a good thing if they do.  It doesn't make sense to pray with a false statement, so a non-Jew shouldn't thank G-d for making them a Jew any more than I should thank G-d for making me a billionaire.  Shema would be borderline, since it does mention ישראל.  Personally I think it's maybe a little weird, but not bad.

Comment: I suspect it isn't elitism but feeling overly connected to and protective of your religion. And thus somewhat violated by this. Also this is often in the context of multiculturalism, a post modern offensive and thoroughly not Jewish attitude in which nothing is more right or wrong than anything else.

Comment: This will depend much on why they are saying it.

Comment: asher kidishanu bmitzvoisov might be a problem (Elokainu also since He is the JEW'S)

Comment: What is the nature of the study group?  Does it have a religious context (like a comparative-religion thing or a "bible study")?  I'm trying to figure out why prayers are being brought in to begin with, which seems like it would be relevant in answering.  Also, welcome to the site!  I get a funny reaction when non-Jews say certain prayers and blessings too; *asher kidshanu* is definitely a problem, but not just that.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21856/can-a-non-jew-recite-the-shema?rq=1  and also see here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88107/can-you-answer-amen-to-a-non-jewish-blessing-or-prayer-of-a-gentile?rq=1